# Asynchronous programming in R

Tags: r, loops, asynchronous, parallel-processing, r-future

## Overview

I am writing a program (in R) that makes API calls at certain designated times. The API calls take a while, but I need the timer (main loop) to continue counting while the API call is made. To do so, I need to "outsource" the API call to another CPU thread. I believe this is possible and have looked into the `future` and `promises` packages, but haven't found a solution yet.

## Reproducible Example

Let's run a `for` loop that counts from 0 to 100. When the counter (`i`) gets to 50, it has to complete a resource-intensive process (calling the function `sampler`, which samples 1 million normal distributions 10,000 times for the sake of taking up computation space). The desire is for the counter to continue counting while `sampler()` is doing its work on another thread.

```
#Something to take up computation space
sampler <- function(){
  for(s in 1:10000) sample(1000000)
}

#Get this counter to continue while sampler() runs on another thread
for(i in 1:100){
  message(i)
  if(i == 50){
    sampler()
  }
}
```

## What I have tried (unsuccessfully)

```
library(future)

sampler <- function(){
  for(s in 1:10000) sample(1000000)
}

for(i in 1:100){
  message(i)
  if(i == 50){
    mySamples <- future({ sampler() }) %plan% multiprocess
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps RStudio's "jobs" function would help? https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/03/14/rstudio-1-2-jobs/

Comment: Looks interesting - thanks for the suggestion. Ideally I would like this to be independent of the IDE.

Comment: In my experience with `future`, splitting a task into separate processes (R doesn't do threads) is great, but you don't return immediately to your primary/main REPL while the other processes work. I've discussed this behavior with its author ([future#293](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/293)), and it is not in the immediate plan to enable this functionality. (I don't know if/how `promises` can be brought to bear here.)

Comment: What should happen with the result of the async process? Does it have to be included somehow in the loop?

Comment: Regarding @r2evans commend: the `future()` function is indeed _non-blocking_, that is, it returns immediately here _as long as there is another worker available_.  What is discussed in https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/293 is a feature request of having futures also not block when all workers are already occupied.

Comment: Thanks for piping in, Henrik, I think I mis-stated (even mis-understood) the underlying mechanisms a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me your call is only blocking while the workers are created, but not for the duration of the actual work. E.g. if do the `plan()` first, the counter will not block:

```
library(future)

sampler <- function(){
  for(s in 1:10000) sample(1000000)
}

plan(multiprocess)

for(i in 1:100){
  message(i)
  if(i == 50){
    mySamples <- future({ sampler() })
  }
}
```

Also note, that the runtime of `sampler()` is much longer than the duration of the blocking call in your code and that, after executing your code, `mySamples` still has the status `resolved: FALSE` and CPU usage is still high.